# Nuxt.js middleware this._router.init is not a function

Tags: middleware, nuxt.js

Using this example https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware to set a middleware I get the error this._router.init is not a function.

In default.vue I have

```
export default {
    router: {
      middleware: 'test'
    },
    ...
}
```

And in middleware I have the file test.js with the following content:

```
export default function (context) {
  context.userAgent = process.server ? context.req.headers['user-agent'] : navigator.userAgent
}
```

Basically I copied whatever was on that page to see if it worked and it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading it wrong. There shouldnt be such thing in default.vue. It says it should be in nuxt config.

```
nuxt.config.js

export default {
  router: {
    middleware: 'stats'
  }
}
```

Or if its for page its without router key

```
export default {
  middleware: 'stats'
}
```